# Size content to viewport

Tags: viewport, google-pagespeed

After running google PageSpeed insights I get the following error:

> The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user to scroll horizontally. Size the page content to the viewport to provide a better user experience.
>   The page content is 745 CSS pixels wide, but the viewport is only 375 CSS pixels wide. The following elements fall outside the viewport:
>   The element `<img src="images/video_img.jpg">` falls outside the viewport.
>   The element `<img src="images/video_bg.png">` falls outside the viewport.

My website is: [Expodine](http://www.expodine.com/)

I've already included viewport in the head section:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```